# Javascript - deserialized json string get value by string

Tags: javascript, html, json

i have following row in 2 nested for loops:

```
document.getElementById("sm" + i + "b" + j).innerHTML = jsonval.values.sm1b1;
                                                                       ^^^^^^
```

i would need to change the variable in the loop like the id of the element. so `"sm" + i + "b" + j`
but to do so I need to have it as a string.. how can I access the variable dynamically by generating the variable name?

Comment: Use square bracket notation `jsonval.values["sm" + i + "b" + j]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try formulating a key (`id`) first, then access the element by that ID. Finally, set the value by using square-bracket notation.

```js
const id = `sm${i}b${j}`;
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = jsonval.values[id];
```

Comment: @sharkyenergy consider accepting the duplicate? This question has already been asked before

Answer (score 0):

if jsonval.values is an object type variable then u can construct ur string using the syntax

```
object[`sm${i}b${j}`]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you think to access the value of values object with :

```
values["sm"+i+"b"+j]
```

instead of :

```
values.sm1b1
```

Comment: Hi @thibault-spriet, welcome to stackoverflow. Please be more elaborate in your answers. You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to write a great answer. Welcome